# Is there a way to grid my google map in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gridview

I've created a map I want to classify my map into Let's say hexagon grids like cellular networks so I can be able to color each hexagon independently, the only work around I found was to manually draw circles using the overlay class and the ondraw method, but in order to manually do so I'll have to create like thousands of circles. I need a hexagrid on the whole map so when I need to color a hexagon I just find it by Let's say it's name or number. does Android support such feature?

Answer (score 0):

No, Android does not have a built-in hexagon overlay for Google Maps. It is conceivable that you could find a third-party component for this, but more likely you will need to implement it yourself.